# Mongodump database Backup Error How it can be solved?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodump

I received this error when I run command of mongodump

```
mongodump --db admin --out /DatabaseBackups/
```

> error getting collections for database `admin`: error running `listCollections`. Database: `admin` Err: not authorized on admin to execute command { listCollections: 1, cursor: {}, $readPreference: { mode: "secondaryPreferred" }, $db: "admin" }

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide username and password in order to authorize:

```
mongodump -h SERVER_NAME:PORT -d DATABASE_NAME -u DATABASE_USER -p PASSWORD
```